# Javascript Regex Object Doesn't Recognize {n,m}

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in JS to recognize any digit up to seven times, followed by a "-" followed by 2 digits followed by "-" followed by a single digit. This is the simple regex I have:

```
/\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d/g
```

This should match strings like:

- `123-12-7`
- `1-12-7`
- `1234567-12-7`

but not `12345678-12-1`

However, the above is returning true. The regex returns true when there is any number of digit in the first group.

Does the JavaScript Regex object not support {n,m}?

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d/);
alert(pattern.test("12345678-13-1"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XTRAc/1/ live example

Comment: Don't do `new RegExp(/\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d/)`.  Either use `pattern = /\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d/;` *or* `pattern = new RegExp('\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d');`, not both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It matches `2345678-13-1`. You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) it to the beginning and end of your string:

```
/^\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d$/
```

Note though, that (as Rocket Hazmat pointed out) you do not need to use the `RegExp` constructor if you use a regex literal (something without string quotes).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bSPg8/)

Answer (score 4):

It does support the [`{min,max}`-syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), but [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) try to find matching substrings. You will have to include [start and end anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Also notice that you should either use the `RegExp` constructor to build a regex from a string *or* a regex literal, but not both (see [MDN: creating regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression)).

```
/^\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d$/
new RegExp("^\\d{1,7}-\\d{2}-\\d$") // the worse choice
```

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing your regex incorrectly. Try this (note the anchors, which ensure the string consists of nothing but your pattern):

```
var pattern= /^\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d$/;
```

Otherwise subsets of the existing string will match your regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to **validate entire input string**, use regex pattern

```
/^\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d$/
```

---

If you need to **validate entire line of input string**, use regex pattern

```
/^\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d$/mg
```

---

If you need to **find matches within input string**, use regex pattern

```
/(?:\D|^)(\d{1,7}-\d{2}-\d)(?!\d)/g
```

...and use `$1` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

It does support the {n,m} part, the problem here is that your example matches `2345678`, so you would need a way of matching the character before the first set of digits